# What are the potential risks of using EF generated classes as models in MVC views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity framework 5 in my MVC application.

I am currently binding my views directly with the types that are generated using POCO generator.

Are there any risks of doing this? Is it a bad design?

Or should I always convert models into view models before binding them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any risks of doing this?

I wouldn't say so. The only risk I can see is that you might loose lots of flexibility and the the presentation will be driven by the domain. Changes to the domain model would directly impact the presentation.

> Is it a bad design?

Yes.

> Or should I always convert models into view models before binding them?

Yes, you should define and use view models. Those classes will provide you with much more control over the presentation layer.

Comment: I would submit that a risk could be POST parameter injection that could cause a property that you did not wanted modified to be modified if you did not apply the proper bind(include|exclude) annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I often start with using the EF class out of laziness, thinking, "this time it'll be different".  But I inevitably grow out of it and convert to using a custom viewmodel class.  There's simply too many slightly different things you want in the view that you don't want in the database... The conversion isn't too painful though, so I haven't really regretted it.